# What is the REGEX expression to split **identifiable word blocks in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I'm developing an **AI** in Java that learns how to form sentences by reading many documents. Its in the **initial stage** and the work is to split ***identifiable words from a given text using REGEX** in Java.

This is my code

```
String text="Oh! my God, You are so FUNNY. I've made it simpler like 'Anything'. Are you happy now?";
        String[] words=engine.getWords(text);
        for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(words[i]);
        }
public String[] getWords(String text)
{
   String[] words=text.split("\\s+");
   return words;
}
```

> However it split the words like

```
Oh!
my
God,
You
are
so
FUNNY.
I've
made
it
simpler
like
'Anything'.
Are
you
happy
now?
```

> And I want it to be

```
Oh
!
my
God
,
You
are
so
FUNNY
.
I
'
ve
made
it
simpler
like
'
Anything
'
.
Are
you
happy
now
?
```

What can be the change in REGEX to accomplish this splitting? Any helps?

Comment: `\s*(?:\b|(?<=\W)(?=\W))\s*` should work. Uses boundaries `\b` to split at word boundaries and a lookbehind/lookahead to split between special characters.

Comment: Wow.! works like a charm. But one problem persists. This REGEX blankly creating white spaces in output. Like 
Oh
!
<SPACE>
my
<SPACE>
God
,
<SPACE>
You
<SPACE>
are
<SPACE>
so
<SPACE>
FUNNY
.
<SPACE>
I
'
ve
<SPACE>
made
<SPACE>
it
<SPACE>
simpler
<SPACE>
like
<SPACE>
'
Anything
'<SPACE>
.
<SPACE>
Are
<SPACE>
you
<SPACE>
happy
<SPACE>
now
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
String[] words = text.split("\\s+|(?<=\\S)\\b|(?=\\p{P})");
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/XYb15z)

Comment: Thank you Bohemian. Almost perfect except one thing. When I pass { Hello 'Dear'. } as input (without braces), It generates 4 words from it. They are { Hello , ' , Dear , '. } I don't know what happened to last word. Can you make it smart?

Comment: @san I noticed that too: try that edit. I think I can reduce it further... I'll let you know.